# Next JS sends Javascript of all pages instead of sending javascript of the required page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

When loading the home page of my website (http://www.validaet.com/). Next JS sends the Javascript of all the pages of my Next JS project instead of sending the javascript of the corresponding page. This also might affect the loading time of the page. I am attaching the screenshot for reference. How do I configure Next JS to download only the javascript of the corresponding pages.

[image]

Stack Used on Frontend: Docker, Nginx, Next JS

Comment: It’s not a bundled single page application

Comment: I don't know.  How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: This probably has to do with ["prefech"](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link), which is `true` by default. Next.js loads the current page, and then pre-loads other pages, so that they are quickly available when the user clicks on a link.

Comment: I also think this is the case. I'll check and let you know

Comment: If you are sure and find a solid solution, you might answer your own question (so that it might help people later, and the state isn't "unanswered"). I'd like to answer myself, but currently have no time to properly proof it.